# ¿Cuál es el tamaño o cantidad de datos que soporta una columna XML en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Tengo una duda, cuando subo un archivo de Excel que contiene 4 columnas se me guardan perfectamente en formato XML en SQL Server y cuando quiere guardar una hoja de Excel que contiene 36 columnas no se guarda nada en mi columna de SQL.

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-BD</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-DD</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPGGRF-10849-CC</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPH1GF-10849-WA</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHG7F-10849-AH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>324</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHG7F-10849-BH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHG7F-10849-CF</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHG7F-10849-CH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHG7F-10849-DH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHGRF-10849-AG</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>628</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHGRF-10849-BH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHGRF-10849-CH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPHGRF-10849-DH</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-AD</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-CD</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-ED</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
    <Sheet1>
        <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
        <Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-HC</Item_x0020_Number>
        <Fecha>02/16 - 02/19</Fecha>
        <Cantidad>0</Cantidad>
    </Sheet1>
</NewDataSet>
```

El XML anterior es lo que se me guarda de mi hoja de Excel con 4 columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La **[documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339(SQL.90).aspx)** (en inglés) dice:

> La representación almacenada de las instancias de tipo de datos xml no puede superar 2 gigabytes (GB) de tamaño.

Si tu información supera este tamaño, me temo que no será posible almacenarlo en base de datos, además de contemplar algún error error de comunicación, parseo del XML, codificación del texto etc.

Nota y recomendación: al incluir más detalles a tu pregunta será más sencillo encontrar el problema, por ejemplo, cuando no te guarda la información ¿te genera alguna excepción?

Comment: :o No!! solo me guarda el id, tengo 2 campos id y xml(alli se debe de guardar lo de excel) y lo demas queda vacio. Pero si es por eso, dudo que se pueda, por que ademas de tener mas de 30 columnas, tiene mas de 400 filas